# Testing series $ \sum\limits_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n + 1}{n - \ln(n)} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a problem which is related to testing the convergence or divergence of a series. For more details:
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n + 1}{n - \ln(n)}
$$
I find it hard to deal with $\ln(n)$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ because $\lim$ can not be applied directly

Comment: Consider when $n$ is even.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I have a comment that $|U_n| \leq \frac{2}{n-ln(n)}$ but I don't know how to do next.

Comment: @Hoang Nam: Look at it as a sequence even though it’s a series . Don’t be too rigid when learning calculus or analysis . Relax and learn.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum\limits_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{2n} + 1}{2n -\ln(2n)}
>\sum_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac 2{2n}=\infty$$
therefore it diverges by comparison test, since the subsequence of all even terms diverges.

Comment: Why $\ln n$ is eliminated from the right part?

Comment: @Hoang, that is how we get strict inequality.

Comment: I am using the fact that $\dfrac1{n-\ln n}>\dfrac 1n\forall n\ge 2$